# How can I model extra arguments with clap?

Tags: rust, clap

Let's say I have a program, `foobar` which must have a `--browser` argument set.

```
foobar --browser chrome
```

Now, I want to add a subcommand,

```
foobar --browser chrome cookies
```

Now, *because* the browser was set to chrome, I want to enable extra arguments for the cookies subcommand,

```
foobar --browser chrome cookies --chrome-foo=bar
```

I do not want `--chrome-foo` to be available for chrome browsers, and only on chrome browsers. Is there a way to model this with `clap`? Can it be done entirely with the derive model?

Comment: Is the `cookies` subcommand shared to all browsers?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, it is. It calls get_cookies on the browser implementation and provides an interface to that. The problem is that different browsers may have different configurations available for cookies.